# Apache 2.2 reverse proxy

Tags: reverse-proxy, apache2.2, proxypass

```
<VirtualHost mydomain.com:80>
    ServerName mydomain.com 
    ProxyRequests     On
    RewriteEngine     On

    EnableMMAP off
    EnableSendfile off

    <Directory />
        AllowOverride none
        Require all denied
    </Directory>    

    Redirect / /principal
    ProxyPass /principal http://localhost:8080/principal
    ProxyPassReverse /sepcogt http://localhost:8080/principal

    ProxyPass /clinica http://localhost:8080/clinica
    ProxyPassReverse /clinica http://localhost:8080/clinica

    ProxyPass /clinicadental http://localhost:8080/clinicadental
    ProxyPassReverse /clinicadental http://localhost:8080/clinicadental

    ProxyPass /colonyrecto http://localhost:8080/colonyrecto
    ProxyPassReverse /colonyrecto http://localhost:8080/colonyrecto
</VirtualHost>
```

Above is the configuration of my httpd.conf but works some times.
In my error.log of the apache shows ever the next log.

```
[Thu May 01 11:31:41 2014] [warn] proxy: No protocol handler was valid for the URL https://ad.doubleclick.net:443/adi/N3175.1220341.GENOME.COM/B4640114.41;sz=160x600;dcopt=rcl;mtfIFPath=nofile;click=http://ads.yahoo.com/clk?3,eJydjVtrgzAYhn9N70QSc3KEXcRDlkrtVshq7V2tqZ3zMNCStb9-dY7tfg8fLy8vD3wQcUQLYA4EUx8a-kAQh5gUfsmYz4ADOOceQxRT4kHsYLe3T9cx2dooO6g4EBNJmBVWzFRT9HN.8aeUIaJDXc3TNhhQ-e2GMFm-i.8TqiYYfvpSCKxKVWNxU6fdJX4NfrXoCNLbuXnWG7zKNp9rnY-plk16BXivc7DSsV3XAuStbPZt7qV.Dx4d5zyOHwskFp68n7XWNV311pnWdBf32LfTjuTdiBgiX9gjXQY=,;ord=1398965499?. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Thu May 01 11:31:42 2014] [error] (OS 10060)A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.  : proxy: HTTP: attempt to connect to 192.155.208.2:80 (*) failed
[Thu May 01 11:31:42 2014] [warn] proxy: No protocol handler was valid for the URL https://ad.doubleclick.net:443/adj/N3175.1220341.GENOME.COM/B4640114.51;abr=!ie;sz=300x250;dcopt=rcl;mtfIFPath=nofile;click=http://ads.yahoo.com/clk?3,eJydjckOgjAARH-ImNYWimk8lE1FwSWsx1IURJbEJYhfr4jRu-.wMplMMhBRVSgECMIx4AqAQKUQy4maEpgeiAQopQTJE4QIkCVlyYJZ1-z9rcH53NRYj62HScsGsl6LIW.U3paOu8MxG6pAu6D0vdWhvTix.9GiNm8--fWH52ldYLa7o-hm-tp3ZsRjt8ir-FHmq3B7d7346nhW6XQwX89MeeWZrVswEFdWuQ596PwOppJ0bsTpWGeCn0eiqZ6ToFVz,;ord=1398965476?. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Thu May 01 11:31:42 2014] [warn] proxy: No protocol handler was valid for the URL https://ad.doubleclick.net:443/adi/N3175.1220341.GENOME.COM/B4640114.53;sz=728x90;dcopt=rcl;mtfIFPath=nofile;click=http://ads.yahoo.com/clk?3,eJydi9FugjAYhZ.GO0Ja264lzS4KlSGxZksQZXfWsk4QXAKu4tNPxuID7Mufk5OT74eIY6j13DASGBwEZs84xEQzQ6n-IB7gnEPAEKGEssDD.tm9DH2aO7nbJ4tQjKTRVjsxYccopv7Kxowj9NRVdprysEPm141guqzF.4mSU9j99aUQODFJhUWOvneXxSZ8aPIAipsC66oeVtu36zorepXFJzXAo2rSepVtbu9SIJXZq5ICKPv4fPa8z77.miExm8f3c875ZWuPbdmU7cU.nJtxR.HdkBBS-AMvp142,;ord=1398965500?. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Thu May 01 11:31:43 2014] [warn] proxy: No protocol handler was valid for the URL https://ad.doubleclick.net:443/adi/N3175.1220341.GENOME.COM/B4640114.53;sz=728x90;dcopt=rcl;mtfIFPath=nofile;click=http://ads.yahoo.com/clk?3,eJydjU2PgjAARP8Q2bS0FEyzh4LiaqzRpAjlJm3DClt7wK.-e8OyWe--w8tkMslARE1jIEZ4FgFNtAoBhThqEh1HCsUBoJQiiDAJcYKCynXxsvdEtPPq-LVI2cg6K5s7m2hHySnvktF5Rrg7tVN1SAekf7cZXK969j5ZW6TuL68YI0PYCcAu-a26Lor0fzavbV1KJLv-vin3j62QFy7yH-5BxO0ebIS222V94qX0sit8.Tr4DILBmN66s.Hq-3hW5kM5-wSWqlgx,;ord=1398965492?. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Thu May 01 11:31:43 2014] [warn] proxy: No protocol handler was valid for the URL https://ad.doubleclick.net:443/adj/N3175.1220341.GENOME.COM/B4640114.51;abr=!ie;sz=300x250;dcopt=rcl;mtfIFPath=nofile;click=http://ads.yahoo.com/clk?3,eJydTV1vgjAU.TW-UWP5EAjZAyBGjaDbUOZjLVXqCt1KSYe.flSW7X0nNzfnnpxzD7QCE.u-iWfYcufQnnswgLZz9kp3jixizIIggJYHbdt3HdcINfY7fFQLhFZJ9Lg3cXFW4YirXuuR7z29l.FMxLfrKB2j1iof3hhu1u.h.xHxJmp.-NCnVq-Hux0Ks3nrkkP0a1vgPs0TJ7slals8f2X5Sab5kqU9pKc6NbfFC03zTX26lSzLU2f3V.BkGJWUHxMrnJjLYZRS064lJUairXhNppjXg1wj0TPUlOBMGQP8AlrECLhwUYOKKyA5uBIJeDNo2kAH3kmgA7IiQJDPjgpSAtroCJKUN8PTb8jSe4A=,;ord=1398965496?. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Thu May 01 11:31:43 2014] [warn] proxy: No protocol handler was valid for the URL https://ad.doubleclick.net:443/adj/N3175.1220341.GENOME.COM/B4640114.53;abr=!ie;sz=728x90;dcopt=rcl;mtfIFPath=nofile;click=http://ads.yahoo.com/clk?3,eJydjVtPg0AUhH9N36DZC1ga4sPuAqEIaCMUeFwuAapcItus8uuFYvTdLyeTOZNJBmIzx0DLYQ6Mh4JX1QGZUNNzozwgWAEFmKaJIEDA0LXjUSEr.q24SCvlrk3vv8eSXJKNepVs8y.Gqg6bU3att-hCJ1zeuwx6pzfyf2jc0-nHnwiR7ms8a-SJuenNjulvzcpwYBEcWmHjJ-fPMMpEEDnvwRfQg8Tr.MiW4ZWArLPRc0Rg8DfwqCiNEOMOkx1ylpNS7ptBFk3FR.HRjvti6JZY8H7mfctV0bR9PaliUMthyb8BQNVj.w==,;ord=1398965477?. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Thu May 01 11:31:43 2014] [warn] proxy: No protocol handler was valid for the URL https://ad.doubleclick.net:443/adi/N3175.1220341.GENOME.COM/B4640114.41;sz=160x600;dcopt=rcl;mtfIFPath=nofile;click=http://ads.yahoo.com/clk?3,eJydjc1ugzAQhJ8mN4JsbCdEqAcDcUkUaJFoKUfA.Cc1MtCkefqaUuUB-mk1OxrNaiGydiVM861JADdAlmcbC2KSmXxrAlRqwLIsjBDBxDCJBkkZs.Gyi65unHp7m84cnTi70oVqFrH4V3NW5tw71oRL9G4PiP92HXg8dPT.2M-1.feHHijFHvdaTCukf0z7N.tRc3MYtMn9xa3AKQ5vQZSMfsTO.jcgfsu6U8walcHgniO1jSR8XD5pWj2O.QrRlcHUyGmoC86LPpXjJAs9FxeVNp-8uOl93StfifUo06.irDyGcLOWYhgyIcVU1T9Lxmlp,;ord=1398965501?. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Thu May 01 11:31:44 2014] [warn] proxy: No protocol handler was valid for the URL https://ad.doubleclick.net:443/adj/N3175.1220341.GENOME.COM/B4640114.53;abr=!ie;sz=728x90;dcopt=rcl;mtfIFPath=nofile;click=http://ads.yahoo.com/clk?3,eJydjUtvgzAQhH9NbiSKMa8K9WBDEEE8GjUE6M1gAiYUUAN1wq8PhKq9d7Sanf000gKog0ze0kx5OQMqEyCKOpDkVKMqFFVN2Oq6DhUAVEWVoSSgWe6QnbgZE3uHn7djRClHi4rZkiW.abNbxhgbVbGgE75C-uwawNlf0P-FwwZff.IeIW6.h6OEbqMdD7sQ.9bMRA7M-uKP3t2NDjf.mPTe0aq9O2AflVO7kcUC88ADs-BehSv.78GrIJR9360gWonWNJzzTdnyrMxJ13-xbpO1nxP-JhnpWdusWbOmQ0rYxM55Tqf1AOHXZlw=,;ord=1398965481?. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Thu May 01 11:31:44 2014] [warn] proxy: No protocol handler was valid for the URL https://ad.doubleclick.net:443/adi/N3175.1220341.GENOME.COM/B4640114.41;sz=160x600;dcopt=rcl;mtfIFPath=nofile;click=http://ads.yahoo.com/clk?3,eJydjVlvgkAUhX-Nb2hghjWkD8NWNIK1ZVHfBmZkkaXBMVP59WJp2vd-uTk5ueckR4ImPqsaNs4q0HMoApiZkqxkOtE0gxJBNE3TUAEUFV1ShL2.S17JjSTcSbHvWujJxk4zjmaKp.Szf9Of6tmgtutifiXWFZLvri1t1hf0f-xDZ11..Boh7n.Eo4xOXXe4ubH1W3NyMRxzGDrv9Tbdf4XRkQWR1wR3qQyci7yNSBU68biLgvsRuOD0N.AiCCVjnwuIFsCbjnO-KgaKGe-HhrSUVHiV9-2UFHSoMBuqfNnSjuFmWVLcsHJKHv2cZ38=,;ord=1398965500?. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Thu May 01 11:31:45 2014] [warn] proxy: No protocol handler was valid for the URL https://ad.doubleclick.net:443/adj/N3175.1220341.GENOME.COM/B4640114.53;abr=!ie;sz=728x90;dcopt=rcl;mtfIFPath=nofile;click=http://ads.yahoo.com/clk?3,eJydjV1rgzAUhn9N72TkqzUSdpH4UStVNma15k6Nq1M7B7HY.vs1dWz3ezk8vJzzwIGYEdxsUFWXNgIIghIzSNYVVTZxHNsCjDFEwZpCQDeO9Sb663ZOomz2jmXoC24SuXk18yUng2LpL9QwcMFFd6dllQmN1cN1YbTr-f8jyCD0T99xTkIVdoRz8Hm8-Afxq3myj9MDkp0a9vnrNUmLKU6DIb4BIs9Zu899XKD4Jrf-LNMeJH8Pni2rnaavFeYrFNxH1-04Dga6GT709FSPZ3PBwd3xEIDvTaO-AVd8X8Y=,;ord=1398965487?. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Thu May 01 11:31:47 2014] [warn] proxy: No protocol handler was valid for the URL https://choices.truste.com:443/ca?pid=tradedesk01&aid=tradedesk01&cid=0511td160x600&c=tradedesk01cont2&w=160&h=600&plc=tr. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Thu May 01 11:31:47 2014] [warn] proxy: No protocol handler was valid for the URL https://mf.sitescout.com:443/disp?pid=F42447E&rnd=1398965502&cm=http://ads.yahoo.com/clk?3,eJydjc1ugzAQhJ8mNxxhfgwI9WCTILUKFCQawhGMBSQBIuxgytOXhKi9d7RafTva3YG6qyGnhJBCVJgMQctyoWEWdmnZhm0oquu6muloCOkO0hX8UPRJj9ILtJqS54xPMoxXwhV-xzhbObIf3ffU0TtXq3UkXC.lgwhK1Jf5L5G-I.zFS-Tys9rZ2Mqi033.RX7XdlQLko8mO8fykMZTmGQiSPxr8A3rMPXrQxLP4UyacMZzlu6n4C.gTVFqIW4bHW80fykp5fbOWUnzgdd9y7a0bxe7aCWgfUfZTYDJAMXA8gtfnJENgOYd4PkIrk1Vi67pKsDF0FwYELKhbDn-AUuxcn8=,. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Thu May 01 11:31:48 2014] [warn] proxy: No protocol handler was valid for the URL https://ad.doubleclick.net:443/adi/N3175.1220341.GENOME.COM/B4640114.53;sz=728x90;dcopt=rcl;mtfIFPath=nofile;click=http://ads.yahoo.com/clk?3,eJydi91ugkAUhJ.GOzD7h4WQXiwoEYNbmyJI72B3BUFKw0JofXpBGh-gk5MvcyYzENsizZA4S4RMyyKZSG1IjMwULxY2uAZs28YIWyuyIhbU6KTDG4-G9SndbpzHv3PjbKCz8gnJ7A.mRM8FrVvmcxQ5CotH14U7v6L.l9N8OerP-5QO24.jjVBoBKd-c3SetTUnLKxAUlYgiN9.WJh0-9C77n.hhaHPOoijmt28gpVOzZAPWP5cvmpa0XXfC0wXyBtvGIZlr6TgaauKppZL3tRjjADE-rlpxQjeK11eJe.aC9fbJhV6J1U3lu4ZC2ki,;ord=1398965506?. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Thu May 01 11:31:49 2014] [warn] proxy: No protocol handler was valid for the URL https://4236808.fls.doubleclick.net:443/activityi;src=4236808;type=invmedia;cat=ijhardnr;ord=8384921548000.65. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Thu May 01 11:31:51 2014] [warn] proxy: No protocol handler was valid for the URL https://ad.doubleclick.net:443/adj/N3175.1220341.GENOME.COM/B4640114.51;abr=!ie;sz=300x250;dcopt=rcl;mtfIFPath=nofile;click=http://ads.yahoo.com/clk?3,eJydjV9rgzAUxT9N32QYE11A9pBoUyuNrEzrmjf.pLqoOIjFdp9-ZpZ-gB0uPw73nsMF0HcvpXQqLKWEsCwc6APklrh-RbiqLdv3fQd7roddG0Prg3a33ZzEpzksimhLiVEc5OVMVjUG-9W.Y0MW2FetmnV1ohrWf9kAxPuO.F8U9VQ..PIPRXWkEOGZ-rxuM.qMhUIJlYEk5PdDfrwl6XniKev53UYibbtDKgaRH23-w4ZEMXVuns03y2qn6XsDycZhy-iqHcfeQMv-S08v1TiYC2RLJgQe.AV48GAG,;ord=1398965487?. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Thu May 01 11:31:51 2014] [warn] proxy: No protocol handler was valid for the URL https://ad.doubleclick.net:443/adi/N3175.1220341.GENOME.COM/B4640114.53;sz=728x90;dcopt=rcl;mtfIFPath=nofile;click=http://ads.yahoo.com/clk?3,eJydTG1vgjAY.DV-o4byMiFkHwrKxKjohqD7VkqBOqQblHTj1w9k8Qfs8uRyz-XuoO7YmpFZRLVti9DcJtiBhpla2cLWKFFUx3GgBhdQf4KWqaARh5DEcnnG65V7.zdekko0oRjpMumDNbLvqY13LSYrdls9u2c9uAk-0P.h8tpt.3SAkFy.nXoDvZvbc7c6uY.Ykhj7ZdGHSVxtk-P3PrqIXeRXux.VDF9e2TaJ2a73r2EUGGF0VC.Fo.msKKUQnzMdzTR.OCnlvGtpRnDTlvxG54TfBrviHWsZrjFIWVUBnoMWVxTkvLmBkksgOCioALwevDHABt0JgOsMiJKChn51rKEZYPVYwYLxelj9BS3RfEE=,;ord=1398965506?. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Thu May 01 11:31:52 2014] [warn] proxy: No protocol handler was valid for the URL https://ad.doubleclick.net:443/adj/N3175.1220341.GENOME.COM/B4640114.51;abr=!ie;sz=300x250;dcopt=rcl;mtfIFPath=nofile;click=http://ads.yahoo.com/clk?3,eJydjUlvgzAQhX9NbhhhTAAL9cASkqAQFQlK4caWQFiMgNT039eELuqhlz6NZp7mfaOBSEtwjgUFF9klU9UUIQ1K21TNFVmWJU7QNA2hLcJYUhXI1cFh3PcG9K9Wkhx2hr7IMcOU6quuSzuu.lldum2KGJXeunoxRpQ.WBM6x1r.v6zcm8mnZ..ELnUtSbduw-t9Fxg.WFxGojeffZ2ewmVGk-vbjfsOq7Mf305-00Z-gOLQaeO9Xbn0-.KJ48pp6jdI34g2K0opX3RTUnUtG5QMTc5npGVJ1eXFzPdlzzyLiuELAikh9ci2CEngd5KRe0-6BwBEcCEDgAKo27EH09vf6AeQUIT7,;ord=1398965484?. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Thu May 01 11:31:52 2014] [warn] proxy: No protocol handler was valid for the URL https://ad.doubleclick.net:443/adi/N3175.1220341.GENOME.COM/B4640114.41;sz=160x600;dcopt=rcl;mtfIFPath=nofile;click=http://ads.yahoo.com/clk?3,eJydi91OgzAYhq9mZ4T0j1HTeFBg2JGVOIPD7gwKweEKRlgqXr1jmF2AT768efPm-SBmDwXVugIFqT0K1hgwSLySVr5fQuIAxhhB0Ac-8gh0iNvbp2lMDjbKC7EJ-EwS5qXlC80c.dKf6ZxxiNdD2yzTIRhwdXNDmGw.-P8JxTkY.vqWcyIq0RLeiq-3y-Y1uGuRBirbg.RH2V2-.04zNcosPssJnlSmpl32YlJzNLKVSEbaHpv756PjvI.j5wrzFYqvZ6116645dbWpu4urezPvOL4akUfRL6lZXmE=,;ord=1398965500?. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Thu May 01 11:31:53 2014] [warn] proxy: No protocol handler was valid for the URL https://ad.doubleclick.net:443/adj/N3175.1220341.GENOME.COM/B4640114.53;abr=!ie;sz=728x90;dcopt=rcl;mtfIFPath=nofile;click=http://ads.yahoo.com/clk?3,eJydi91ugkAUhJ.GOzD7h4WQXiwoEYNbmyJI72B3BUFKw0JofXpBGh-gk5MvcyYzENsizZA4S4RMyyKZSG1IjMwULxY2uAZs28YIWyuyIhbU6KTDG4-G9SndbpzHv3PjbKCz8gnJ7A.mRM8FrVvmcxQ5CotH14U7v6L.l9N8OerP-5QO24.jjVBoBKd-c3SetTUnLKxAUlYgiN9.WJh0-9C77n.hhaHPOoijmt28gpVOzZAPWP5cvmpa0XXfC0wXyBtvGIZlr6TgaauKppZL3tRjjADE-rlpxQjeK11eJe.aC9fbJhV6J1U3lu4ZC2ki,;ord=1398965506?. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Thu May 01 11:31:54 2014] [warn] proxy: No protocol handler was valid for the URL https://ad.doubleclick.net:443/adj/N3175.1220341.GENOME.COM/B4640114.53;abr=!ie;sz=728x90;dcopt=rcl;mtfIFPath=nofile;click=http://ads.yahoo.com/clk?3,eJydi9tugzAQRL8mbxAZDAGE-mBuBRRoI7kh9A2wC8QQEJjm8vWFUuUDOlrNnh3NStCEkMiUAJLDHcxhkZmSouY60RQDFgIwTVPWgAx3mibrgqR-JR5vDXx1TpnvWmhRaCf5Fa0qF0tXftcX9-wH8-rDGh2tEZLfri2FAUP.l.VaWd0fBwgpPvHPChrB-TS5H9az5nyyyGH3GFfNPjncYpzyCHtNdAdq3LryHgcwfoTszXFBhI8sLZ-fL4JQcd5vINrI3jzDNFaUENpnA58Gui26dk7rC6G3bV.1M5edyIfsmzYzQwPoYtmttzjOuxdrQi-85vcfFWJu0w==,;ord=1398965487?. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Thu May 01 11:31:55 2014] [warn] proxy: No protocol handler was valid for the URL https://ad.doubleclick.net:443/adj/N3175.1220341.GENOME.COM/B4640114.53;abr=!ie;sz=728x90;dcopt=rcl;mtfIFPath=nofile;click=http://ads.yahoo.com/clk?3,eJydjU2PgjAARP8Q2bS0FEyzh4LiaqzRpAjlJm3DClt7wK.-e8OyWe--w8tkMslARE1jIEZ4FgFNtAoBhThqEh1HCsUBoJQiiDAJcYKCynXxsvdEtPPq-LVI2cg6K5s7m2hHySnvktF5Rrg7tVN1SAekf7cZXK969j5ZW6TuL68YI0PYCcAu-a26Lor0fzavbV1KJLv-vin3j62QFy7yH-5BxO0ebIS222V94qX0sit8.Tr4DILBmN66s.Hq-3hW5kM5-wSWqlgx,;ord=1398965492?. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Thu May 01 11:31:56 2014] [warn] proxy: No protocol handler was valid for the URL https://ad.doubleclick.net:443/adi/N3175.1220341.GENOME.COM/B4640114.41;sz=160x600;dcopt=rcl;mtfIFPath=nofile;click=http://ads.yahoo.com/clk?3,eJydS21vgjAY.DV-AyMtKIbsQ3mbEjAzU5F9K221zEqJrenw1w918Qfs8uTunsudA4MpmR0oIR7EwPFqOAkc16t9OvPxnFmTIAigOwH-3Jv6wEJ35FeyM3GJF0n4-LOorA164ngn-fQf.p3T6LaPvo.PaBcqSB.dyMmWJ.R.hNs2VH9-iZBZfG5vLkrcy.6abMNXLSawiLNTBTKel-uf1abSxSYVRe.wVUxAXmbnr.dUVBtyK-K1qdav5Ztlca27EUQjkA5njBlzaQhnuNOXphsTeR7iTnZXgS82l6KhuLcpU7ppsW5ka2vObMX6YSIEU3ajBG6pGkYHxuggv4UCc2g=,;ord=1398965504?. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
[Thu May 01 11:31:56 2014] [warn] proxy: No protocol handler was valid for the URL https://ad.doubleclick.net:443/adi/N3175.1220341.GENOME.COM/B4640114.53;sz=728x90;dcopt=rcl;mtfIFPath=nofile;click=http://ads.yahoo.com/clk?3,eJydi9uOgjAURb.GN0IoLbWk8aHcREbIkFSReROKHUFxEjAVv14R4wfMysnOzs46AFK7xBARTIoDKLBZzilAVkHEfC9srBmUUmAbFjFsoCH9opZDH22Vt9uHvsNGIjcrFJuQY-RT.yZjBi7EXS2naet0ULxcF0Srhv0fNzw53buvGEOhCGvE.C-4u.ob56N5ok54YyVZOqyz9JbwvI95cIoHcIzvDK15A.O7HH681Mi5vMXp53Ohab99.zeDbGYGz1NK6VUrj211rtqrXl7O4w6Dp-EhaD4A9eRddQ==,;ord=1398965513?. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
```

also shows.

```
[Thu May 01 11:30:58 2014] [warn] (OS 64)The specified network name is no longer available.  : winnt_accept: Asynchronous AcceptEx failed.
[Thu May 01 11:31:02 2014] [warn] (OS 64)The specified network name is no longer available.  : winnt_accept: Asynchronous AcceptEx failed.
```

This configuration some times works fine and many times wrong, I try everything.

Answer (score 0):

Make ProxyRequests Off....as 'On' is for forward proxy and you are trying to use reverse proxy....